# Convert curl url to Postman

Tags: api, postman

I have this line that works with curl in the terminal

`curl http://api.ruby_api.dev/users/1 -H 'Authorization: Token token="t44FEqfDav/o7ZSIqCgpzA6h/4fShgihdgISqjpAx/4Y+R0dmopv6Zwm4Sy3BWulLCnRsvUoH3+3IzhZ9eu+gA==", email="test@gmail.com"'`

How do I manage the same with postman? I have never worked with postman before :/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed it. I included the email in the same header as token